# Como o JQuery consegue ser ao mesmo tempo função e objeto?

Tags: jquery, funções

Conheço pouco de Javascript, e estava tentando entender como o JQuery consegue ser uma função e um objeto ao mesmo tempo. Fiquei pensando como ele foi desenvolvido para que pudesse ser chamado como função (`$()`) e e como objeto (`$.fn()`).
Alguém sabe como isso funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é do jQuery, mas um aspecto do próprio JavaScript, onde *todas as funções são objetos*.

**Exemplos:**

```
var obj = function(){
  alert('Olá!');
}

obj.ola = "Olá de novo!";

obj(); // exibe "Olá!"
alert(obj.ola); // exibe "Olá de novo!"
```

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223609/1377664)